# Convolution of two identical functions and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I have the following problem to solve:

> Express the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1+(x-t)^2}dx$$ in terms of $t$.

---

My solution is as follows:

We quickly realize that we have that the integral is just the convolution $f * f$ where

$$f := \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Furthermore, if we define the integral as $I(t)$, we have that $\mathcal{F}(I) = \mathcal{F}(f * f) = (\mathcal{F}(f))^2 $. So,

$$I(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}((\mathcal{F}(f))^2)$$

Now $\mathcal{F}(f) = \pi e^{-|x|}$, so

$$(\mathcal{F}(f))^2 = \pi^2 e^{-|2x|} = 2\pi \cdot \pi/2e^{-|2x|} = \mathcal{F}\left(2\pi \frac{1}{1+(2t)^2}\right)$$

And so by the property of uniqueness for Fourier transform, we have that: $$I = 2\pi \frac{1}{1+4t^2}$$

Is this correct? And also, is there any other easier way to solve it? Also, I'm struggling oftenly to keep $x$ and $t$'s separated which makes me confused whether I should do the inverse fourier or the regular Fourier transform of a function. Is there any easy trick to distinguish these variables?

Comment: It seems like you could try partial fractions. Write $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1+(x-t)^2}=\frac{a+bx}{1+x^2}+\frac{c+dx}{1+(x-t)^2}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are functions of $t.$ This should work for all $t\neq 0.$

Comment: This is a problem that is really well-suited to Fourier-transform methods, as you observed. Your method is fine, and assuming you kept careful track of where the factors of $\pi,\sqrt\pi,\dots$, etc. all go, your solution should be correct. If you want someone to verify for you if it's 100% correct, it may be helpful to edit your post and recall your convention for the Fourier transform.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: What's the significance of considering $t\ne0$? As a function of $t$, $I(t)$ is well-defined for every $t$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz $t\neq 0$ just because this partial fraction decomposition don't work there, not because it is undefined. The value when $t=0$ can be computed with the limit as $t\to 0.$ Essentially, $a,b,c,d$ will end up undefined at $t=0,$ so this approach fails there.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29*1%2F%281%2B%28x-t%29%5E2%29%2C%7Bx%2C-Infinity%2C+Infinity%7D%2CAssumptions-%3Et%3E0%5D) certainly seems to think it's correct (the $t>0$ is just so it doesn't think $t$ might be complex). One suggestion though: use a different variable, such as $k$, for the Fourier transformed functions.

Comment: The error is assuming the transform of $f(ax)$ is $\hat f(ax).$ So the approach is right, you just has the wrong last step.

Comment: If $\hat f(x)$ is the transform of $f$ then $\frac1{|a|}\hat f(x/a)$ is the transform of $f(ax).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sorry, too long for a comment*

As @eyeballfrog provided the link in the comment, WolframAlpha gives $\displaystyle I(t)=\frac{2\pi}{4+t^2}$ (please, pay attention that not $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{1+4t^2}$).

I may suppose thay you define FT as $\displaystyle \hat f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}dx$. In this case you do get $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{1+x^2}dx=\pi e^{-|k|}$.

To find an answer, you could also use the Plancherel' theorem ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem)), which states (for the above chosen FT) that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g^*(x)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(k)\hat g^*(k)dk$$
Taking $\,\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2},\,\, f(x)=\frac{1}{1+(x-t)^2}$, you get $\,\displaystyle \hat g(k)=\pi e^{-|k|}; \hat f(k)=\pi e^{-|k|}e^{ikt}$
$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|k|}e^{ikx}dk=\pi\, \Re\,\int_0^\infty e^{-2k}e^{ikx}dk=\pi\, \Re\,\frac{1}{2-it}=\frac{2\pi}{4+t^2}$$

Comment: Nice answer, I'll look into that theorem. Have never seen it before so it should be fun!

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Thomas Andrews. Do the partial fractions as:
$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+(t-x)^2)}= \frac{Ax+B}{1+x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{1+(t-x)^2}.....(1)$$
One gets $$A=\frac{2}{t(4+t^2)}, B=\frac{1}{4+t^2}, C=\frac{-2}{t(4+t^2)}, D=\frac{3}{(4+t^2)}.$$
While integrating (1) from $x=-\infty$ to $x=\infty$ the integral multiplied to $A$ vanishes and we get
$$\implies I=\frac{1}{4+t^2} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}dx+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+(t-x)^,}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2(t-x)dx}{1+(t-x)^2}\right).$$
Let $t-x=u$, then
$$I=\frac{1}{4+t^2} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}dx+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+u^2}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2udu}{1+u^2}\right).$$
The first two integrals give $\pi+\pi$ and the third one vaishes. Finally
$$I=\frac{2\pi}{4+t^2}.$$

Comment: You forgot the $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ in the integrals. There should be four. Technically $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac x{x^2+1}\,dx$$ and the opposite term don't converge. We have $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}$ converges, but if the two bounds go to infinity separately, they don't. But since the starting integral definitely converges, we can show the $[-R,R]$ case is enough.

Comment: That is what  is with $A$ and it vanises the integrabd being odd.

Comment: Except the limit doesn't even converge. Just because the function is odd doesn't mean the limit converges to $0.$